# how to change the foreground color of the default Matching item for Eclipse in dark theme?

Tags: eclipse

I use devstyle for Eclipse dark theme, after some tuning, it's satisfied, Only for the open resource dialog, such as:

[image]

the foreground color of the default matching item is so unpleasant to eyes.
The clicked item or the hovering item is ok, such as:

[image]

but after losting focus , so is the same, such as:

[image]

And I also found there are some same problem in Perference, such as General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations/Linked Mode.  All of them are List component.

I tried to change the color as I can, but found nothing to change it. Someone knows how to change the color?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the problem on my laptop with win 10. There is no problem.

And now I resolved the problem on my desktop with win 7 through installing one win 10 theme. It's a heavy resolution about it.

I think It's the SWT Problem.